# Guide to enhance my code

Tags: c#, sql-server, progressive-enhancement

This program will copy all records inside the table 1 into table 2 and also write into a text file. After it finishes copied all the records, the records will be delete make the table1 empty before new record is added. i like to enhance my code for example :

1. like inserting code to verify if records empty or not, if got problem in copying the file, or if it is EOF, what should i do??
2. This code was in form_load() and running in win form application, what if, if i run the program exe, i dont what the form to be appeared? i want to make this program like it was running on windows behind. Only error or successful messagebox will appeared?
3. Any help in solution, guidance or reference are very very thankful.

Thank you in advance!

```
//create connection
 SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
   new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=F:\Test2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
//command insert into queries
  SqlCommand cmdCopy = new SqlCommand();
  cmdCopy.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
  cmdCopy.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblSend (ip, msg, date) SELECT ip, msg, date FROM tblOutbox";
  cmdCopy.Connection = sqlConnection1;
//insert into text file
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblOutbox";
  cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
  sqlConnection1.Open();
  StreamWriter tw = File.AppendText("c:\INMS.txt");
  SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  tw.WriteLine("id, ip address, message, datetime");
  while (reader.Read())
  {
   tw.Write(reader["id"].ToString());
   tw.Write(", " + reader["ip"].ToString());
   tw.Write(", " + reader["msg"].ToString());
   tw.WriteLine(", " + reader["date"].ToString());
  }
  tw.WriteLine("Report Generate at : " + DateTime.Now);
  tw.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
  tw.Close();
  reader.Close();
//command delete
  String strDel = "DELETE tblOutbox";
  SqlCommand cmdDel = new SqlCommand(strDel, sqlConnection1);
//sqlConnection1.Open(); //open con

  cmdCopy.ExecuteScalar();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute insert query
  cmdDel.ExecuteScalar();//execute delete query

  sqlConnection1.Close(); //close con
//*****************************************************

}
catch (System.Exception excep)
{
  MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the INSERT SQL, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, my mistakes...i'd edited already. thx

Answer (score 5):

A few suggestions:

- Move it out of the form. Business logic and data access does not belong in the form (View). Move it to a separate class.
- Keep the MessageBox code in the form. That's display logic. The entire try..catch can be moved out of the method; just have the method throw exceptions. And don't catch System.Exception - catch the database one(s) you expect.
- I echo Ty's comments on IDisposable and using statements.
- Read up on [Extract Method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) and the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). This method does a **lot**, and it's long. Break it up.
- Move some of the string hardcodes out. What if your connection string or file paths change? Why not put those in a configuration file (or at least use some constants)?

For starters, anyway. :)

Comment: Dear TrueWill, ill will look into ur suggestions. let u knw if im not understand..thank u very much

Answer (score 4):

That sure is some code and I sure could recommend a lot of things to improve it if you care.

First thing I would do is read up on [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) then I would re-write that DataReader as following.

```
using(StreamWriter tw = File.AppendText("c:\INMS.txt"))
{
    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      tw.WriteLine("id, ip_add, message, datetime");
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         tw.Write(reader["id"].ToString());
         tw.Write(", " + reader["ip_add"].ToString());
         tw.Write(", " + reader["message"].ToString());
         tw.WriteLine(", " + reader["datetime"].ToString());
      }
      tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
      tw.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
   }
}
```

Then after your catch, put the following and remove the close call.

```
finally
{
   sqlConnection1.Dispose(); //close con
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to some of the other answers already given, you might also want to consider protecting the data operation with a **Transaction**.

I assume that you don't want any of the following operation to partially complete:

```
  cmdCopy.ExecuteScalar();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute insert query
  cmdDel.ExecuteScalar();//execute delete query
```

If you are processing MANY rows you might want to batch your updates but that is a whole different issue.

Comment: dear Philip, ill try ur approach..let u knw if im having problem or not understand some parts. Hopefully u still continue in helping me..
thx

Answer (score 2):

Firstly kudos to you for trying to improve your skill and being open to publish your code like this.  I believe that is the first step to being a better programmer, is to have this type of attitude.

Here is an implementation that answers some of your questions.
I have extracted some of the old code into methods and also moved some of the responsibilities to their own classes.

Disclaimer:

- Although the code compiles I didn't run it against a database, therefore there might be a couple of small things I missed.
- I had to stop short on certain refactorings not knowing the exact requirements and also to still try and keep some of the concepts simple.

.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

// Program.cs
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            MailArchiver.Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Application completed successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected error occurred:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}

// Reads new messages from DB, save it to a report file 
// and then clears the table
public static class MailArchiver
{

    public static void Run()
    {
        // Might be a good idea to a datetime suffix 
        ReportWriter.WriteFile(@"c:\INMS.txt");
        CopyAndClearMessages();
    }

    private static void CopyAndClearMessages()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        cn.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlTransaction tx = cn.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                CopyMessages(cn, tx);
                DeleteMessages(cn, tx);
                tx.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                tx.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void DeleteMessages(SqlConnection cn, SqlTransaction tx)
    {
        var sql = "DELETE FROM tblOutbox";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn, tx);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60 * 2;  // timeout 2 minutes 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    private static void CopyMessages(SqlConnection cn, SqlTransaction tx)
    {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO tblSend (ip, msg, date) SELECT ip, msg, date FROM tblOutbox";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn, tx);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60 * 2;  // timeout 2 minutes 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

// Provides database connections to the rest of the app.
public static class DbConnectionFactory
{
    public static SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        // Retrieve connection string from app.config
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MailDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        return cn;
    }
}

// Writes all the data in tblOutbox to a CSV file
public static class ReportWriter
{
    private static SqlDataReader GetData()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        cn.Open();

        try
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblOutbox";
            cmd.Connection = cn;

            return cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void WriteFile(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            // This might be serious, we may overwrite data from the previous run.
            // 1. You might want to throw your own custom exception here, should want to handle this
            //    condition higher up.
            // 2. The logic added here is not the best and added for demonstration purposes only.
            throw new Exception(String.Format("The file [{0}] already exists, move the file and try again"));
        }
        var tw = new StreamWriter(filename);

        try
        {
            // Adds header record that describes the file contents
            tw.WriteLine("id,ip address,message,datetime");

            using (SqlDataReader reader = GetData())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var id = reader["id"].ToString();
                    var ip = reader["ip"].ToString();

                    //msg might contain commas, surround value with double quotes
                    var msg = reader["msg"].ToString();
                    var date = reader["data"].ToString();

                    if (IfValidRecord(id, ip, msg, msg, date))
                    {
                        tw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", id, ip, msg, date));
                    }
                }

                tw.WriteLine("Report generated at : " + DateTime.Now);
                tw.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            tw.Close();
        }

    }

    private static bool IfValidRecord(string id, string ip, string msg, string msg_4, string date)
    {
        // this answers your question on how to handle validation per record.
        // Add required logic here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could shorten this considerably by replacing the try..finally..close blocks with using blocks if you like.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a SELECT query to find the non-empty rows (you seem to get along with the EOF issue).
2. On `form_load` event make the form invisible by program arguments.
3. Why not to use [INSERT INTO](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html) (and then DELETE)?